# quartz.net job not running in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I created a windows service in c#.net, it uses quartz.net to do a job every hour. it works locally and doesn't have any problem. but when I installed it on server 2008 R2, it doesn't work. it starts and no error. I used event log and I undrestood class JobScheduler works but jobs don't fire. please help me.

```
     public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CheckJob>().WithIdentity("MyJob", "group1").Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1").StartNow().WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInHours(1).RepeatForever()).Build();



            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            EventLogging.Log("jobscheduling ok");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLogging.Log("jobscheduler:"+ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it works locally, and not in server - It could be the user account under which the service is running is the issue. Check in start -> run -> `services.msc` the user account, and check if service is running, and account has permissions to do what the job is doing

Comment: I checked it before, user account is administrative.

Comment: If your service and your scheduler are not throwing exceptions then it's most likely a problem with the job. Rather than try and troubleshoot it blind I'd suggest adding a [job listener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with quartz, you can check a free points,

1. Inspect the exe property and ensure it is not blocked
2. Check for the proper connection string
3. Check if the required files are in correct path
4. Try to write logs / enable logging to see what's going wrong

Comment: I tried to write in event log but execute method of job doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable scope issue, because you are not keeping a reference to the scheduler outside of the Start method. In order for the scheduler to keep running after the Start method finishes running, the scheduler variable needs to be defined as a static variable, and not as a method variable.

Comment: Try providing more information so that others can help you. You haven't even provided the configuration files for your local vs the server environment. Also, update your code example as the scoping issue still remains in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quartz.server that comes with the package download.

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet

Once you feel comfortable with the framework - then create your own.